In c++ when checking for nullptr, is there a reason to use if(!(x==nullptr)) instead of if(x!=nullptr), are they different?
I'm working through a c++ course and currently covering checking for nullptr's.
The suggested code is:
int* p{};

if(!(p==nullptr)){

etc, etc
But I'm not sure why I can't say (which seems slightly simpler):
if(p!=nullptr){

etc etc
Running the code I get what I would expect both ways. Is there a practical difference I'm missing?

There is no difference.

Have they taught you about != yet? Maybe they just haven't gone over that.

I just use if (p) { /*...*/ } because a zero pointer (or null pointer) is falsey, but a non-zero pointer is truthy.

In your sample code, there is no difference, since p is a raw pointer type.    Practically, with most modern optimising compilers [when compiling with optimisation], the two samples of code would often be translated to exactly the same instructions (based on whatever is known to be most efficient on the target machine).

Usually better to if (p == nullptr) { /* handle error */ } rather than if (p) { /* everything indented */ }. Obviously this depends, but the key is to handle any error and be done with it. Then all your code for the success case isn't indented inside an if () block.

Thank you all very much! Getting all this explanation is a huge help.

@user2357112 To be honest I'm still having to go back and refer to old stuff a lot and it hasn't all stuck yet. But so far I'm used to seeing != in examples which is why this alternative threw me

They are the same for pointers; but if p is a class object that overrides the != and == operators, it could change the meaning (and in C++ sometimes code is changed simply by updating the type). But if it does change the meaning then (and it will depend) we could argue the class is badly written.
BUT
One of the most important things in coding is readability.
This:
if ( !(p == nullptr)) {

is not as readable (in my subjective opinion) as:
if (p != nullptr) {


Always prefer to make things as readable as possible.
When writing classes try and make sure things work as expect (principle of least surprise).


For pointers I personally find simply if (p) and if (!p) to be most readable.

For an actual pointer, like in your case, there's no difference.
But there is a difference if p is not a pointer, but an instance of some custom class. This is because the class could have overloaded both the == and != operators.
This overloading issue is also a problem for the simple if (p) (or if (!p)).

If a class has overloaded operators in a way that they are not opposite to each other (e.g. so if (!(p == nullptr) == (p!=nullptr))  or if ((p) == !(!p)) can test false) then that is typically a concern for the user of that class.    In practice, very few classes will need to have such a behaviour, and those which do will need to be thoroughly documented.   [The most common need for such behaviour I've encountered is in a teaching setting, to demonstrate to students that it is possible and that it is usually best avoided].

Thanks for taking the time! It's really helpful getting the additional context re if p was a class
